# iOS Swift 3 WKWebView Progress Bar Not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, progress-bar, wkwebview

I'm trying to create an iOS WebView app that loads a site and allows users to log in and make purchases. I'm trying to have a progress bar display when loading pages but the progress doesn't display at all and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I also have a pull to refresh view but without a progress bar I can't be sure this is working either. This is my code, any help would be much appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
// Define Views
var webView: WKWebView!
var progressView: UIProgressView!

override func loadView() {
    // Load Initial WebView
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Create Progress View
    progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progressView.sizeToFit()
    let progressButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressView)
    toolbarItems = [progressButton]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    //Set and Load Initial URL
    let url = URL(string: "https://shop.nygmarose.com/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    // Set WebView Config
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    webView.scrollView.bounces = true
    // Allow Scroll to Refresh
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
}

func refreshWebView() {
    // On Scroll to Refresh, Reload Current Page
    webView.reload()
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // Display Progress Bar While Loading Pages
    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
        progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

Comment: I have checked it's woking perfect @Musa

Comment: @iOSDev It's working for you? It could be a problem with my xcode emulator I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and it's working perfect, check here is the output

let me know for more.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it isn't displaying in my emulator but it must be my end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to force the use of the main thread? UI updates are only guaranteed on the main thread.

For example:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // Display Progress Bar While Loading Pages
    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {

        // force main thread async call
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            // do UI update
            progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)

        })
    }
}
```